# Perl Regex word [max 7characters] word

Tags: regex, perl

I need to remove text which matches this kind of pattern. I am working of tool which requires regex written in PERL(rxrepl.exe). I already did the first step to make it easier- deleted all symbols of end of line. 
Now i have only to discover how to correct this regex in PERL regular Expression.

```
My pattern:   <table cellpadding="5".*<blockquote>.{4,10}.*</blockquote></td></tr></table>
```

=== example of file

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>TITLE 25</b></font><br><font color="#808080">18-06-2015 | <a href="http://www.link1.co.uk/" target="_top">Web page</a> | <a href="" target="_top">Local page</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #f8f8f8;"><!-- F5F2C7 -->
<blockquote>
<a href="">HMRC relaxes PAYE late filing penalties</a><br><br>HMRC will begin relaxing automatic late filing penalties for people who send PAYE information late, officials have...
      <br><br><a href="http://www.gogle.com">Employers 'feel the pinch' of skills shortages</a><br>
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<br>

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>TITLE 2</b></font><br><font color="#808080"> | <a href="http://www.TITLE2.com/" target="_top">Web page</a> | <a href="" target="_top">Local page</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #f8f8f8;"><!-- F5F2C7 -->
<blockquote>
<br>
</blockquote>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<br>

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #d0d0d0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #eaeaea;"><!-- F1E896 -->
<font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>TEST80</b></font><br><font color="#808080">18-06-2015 | <a href="https://TEST2.CO.UK" target="_top">Web page</a> | <a href="" target="_top">Local page</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #f8f8f8;"><!-- F5F2C7 -->
<blockquote>


 TEXT SAMPLE TEXT
    </blockquote>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <br>
```

edit: to be clear
I want to remove everything from `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">` to `</table>` IF text between `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>` is shorter than 10. 
Thanks for help:)

Comment: Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: I need to do this replacement regularly not one time only so it would be nice to just write a bat file

Comment: Do you want to remove the <blockquote> tags as well as what is between them, or just what is between them?

Comment: Make a research about XPath, I think this will save your life.

Comment: I want to remove everything from <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"> to </table> IF text between <blockquote> and </blockquote> is shorter than 10.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use an HTML parser instead; it's more reliable and much less likely to randomly break on input you didn't expect. That said,

```
<blockquote>.{4,10}.*</blockquote>
```

The `.{4,10}.*` you have there will match any character, 4 to 10 times, followed by any number of characters. If you only want to match where there's up to 10 characters, removing the `.*` should be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly pointed @ilberkyr it match even spaces.

```
<blockquote> 

Some Text THISWILLNOTBEREMOVED
</blockquote>

@ARR = <HTML>;
$LINE = $ARR =~ /<blockquote>(..)</blockquote>/g;
@lines = split(/\s+/, $LINE);
```

If you want to remove character length between 0 to 10 try splitting with space, for each array value check text length if lesser don't write to the HTML file. You should also manage on the " tags